# How to fix a toilet which continuously runs

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Yesterday I saw the water of my toilet kept running. The gap at the arrow did not close.

May I know what should I buy to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Not related to the toilet flapper problem - it's hard to tell in the picture, but does the white tube pour water into the black tube? If it doesn't, it should. This is what refills the bowl between flushes. If the water level in the bowl is always low then adjusting the white tube will help.

Comment: you need a toilet repair kit, a flapper with some widgets to ensure a fit. should be cheapish.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing to check:  is the chain from the white rod down to the flapper valve tangled and thus too short to let the flapper valve fully down onto its seat?

Answer (score 1):

First, clean the base of your toilet tank and, with a soft cloth, the underside of the existing flapper.  Don't worry, that's clean water.

Second, if after cleaning you don't get a good seal, then what you want is a "toilet flapper".

Such as [this example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Korky-3-in-Premium-Universal-Toilet-Tank-Flapper-3060CM/202183799).

Comment: Take the old one with you to the hardware store. These some in many designs and sizes.